# Como escapar uma chave/chavetas no Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

No Blade, os caracteres chave (ou chaveta) tem como finalidade adicionar a finalidade de impressão do conteúdo. Ele é compliado para um `echo`.

Porém estava pensando se eu precisasse realmente exibir um conteúdo, contendo exatamente o valor das chaves, o que eu poderia fazer?

Por exemplo, se eu precisasse exibir o conteúdo abaixo, como eu poderia "escapar" esses caracteres no Blade?

```
{{ $variavel }} Isso vai ser compilado.

{{ Essa parte tem que ser exibida literalmente no HTML }}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema da pergunta para ganhar -1? Poderia dar detalhes naquilo que pode ser melhorado?

Comment: De nada, percebi mal o que queria. Comentário apagado

Comment: não entendi porque negativaram.... +1 para equilibrar..

Comment: Eu também não, até me parece ser uma questão que pode surgir frequentemente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione um @ para escrever as chaves (curly brackets) de forma literal

```
@{{ $var }}
```

exibirá literalmente

```
@{{ $var }}
```

Se não me engano, no Laravel menor que 5.1, não tinha esse recurso então fazíamos com HTMLEntities.
Mas em testes realizados pelo próprio AP, foi constatado que o recurso está disponível na versão 4.2 do Laravel.

Comment: Essa vai ser uma boa solução para não ficar configurando as tags de interpolação das chaves no Angular JS. Mas nas versões anteriores não teria muita solução.

Comment: Testei no Laravel 4.2 e funcionou também.